# Read a string with a particular format

Tags: c#

I have some strings like

```
string text = 
  "these all are strings, 000_00_0 and more strings are there I have here 649_17_8, and more with this format 975_63_7."
```

So here I wanted to read only `000_00_0`, `649_17_8`, `975_64_7`...   All the string with this format.

Please help me with the situation

Comment: Seems like a job for regular expressions...

Comment: pattern : ([0-9]{3}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{1})

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex` class and its Matches method.

```
var matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(input, "([_0-9]+)");

var numberishs1 = matches
        .Select(m => m.Groups[1].ToString())
        .ToList();

var s1 = string.Join(", ", numberishs1);
```

```
// .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0
these all are strings, 000_00_0 and more strings are there I have here 649_17_8, and more with this format 975_63_7.
000_00_0, 649_17_8, 975_63_7
```

Comment: Probably `[0-9]+(_[0-9]+)*` will be a safier pattern, since `[_0-9]+` matches single `_` whenever it appears, e.g. in `"some_text_only"`

Answer (score -1):

You have to use regular expression.

In your case you want to find the pattern `"..._.._."`
If you only want numbers it would be pattern `"([0-9]{3}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{1})"`

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SyntaxTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input =
                "these all are strings, 000_00_0 and more strings are there I have here 649_17_8, and more with this format 975_63_7.";
            var pattern = "..._.._.";

            Match result = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
            if (result.Success)
            {
                while (result.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Match: {0}", result.Value);
                    result = result.NextMatch();
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```